# How to loop through a set (not a list) of rules in prolog

Tags: prolog

first off thank you for taking the time to consider my question. I'm writing an adventure-style game in prolog as a way to try to learn it. I wrote the following snippet of code:

```
i_am_at(melba_market_square).

exits :-
    i_am_at(X),
    path(X, Y, Z),
    write('Exits: '), nl, 
    write(Y), write(': '), write(Z), nl.

path(melba_market_square, s, melba_armory).
path(melba_market_square, n, melba_main_st_s).
path(melba_market_square, w, melba_sidra_alley_s).
```

What I can't figure out/find how to do is make the "exits" command return all 3 paths at once instead of making me hit the space bar each time. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I thank you for your input, but I'm not quite sure how to use findall for what I need. Would you please elaborate for me? Thank you.]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured it out thanks to the help posted here. Here's my code:

```
i_am_at(melba_market_square).

exits :-
    i_am_at(X),
    path(X, Y, Z),
    write('Exits: '), nl, 
    write(Y), write(': '), write(Z), nl.

path(melba_market_square, s, melba_armory).
path(melba_market_square, n, melba_main_st_s).
path(melba_market_square, w, melba_sidra_alley_s).

zzz :- /* This implements "User"'s where_to_go rule. */
    i_am_at(X),
    where_to_go(X, IntoDirections),
    write('Exits: '), write(IntoDirections), nl.

where_to_go(From, IntoDirections) :- 
    findall(Direction, path(From, Direction, _), IntoDirections).
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it out but it should like this I think:

```
where_to_go(From, IntoDirections) :- findall(Direction, path(From, Direction, _), IntoDirections).
```

`IntoDirections` should list all directions that you are able to go.

Comment: Thank you, User, for the suggestion. I'm having trouble getting it to work though. Here's the latest thing I've tried: zzz :-
 where_to_go(i_am_at(X), IntoDirections),
 write(X),
 printList(IntoDirections), nl.

where_to_go(From, IntoDirections) :- 
 findall(Direction, path(From, Direction, _), IntoDirections),
 write(IntoDirections), nl.

printList([]) :- write("").
printList([H|T]) :- write(H), printList(T).